# RadioButtons causing built-in .net form validation to malfunction

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a very basic form in a .Net page, it has 6 fields each with a requiredfieldvalidator attached. Everything works fine and the form is stopped if even one field is blank. I was asked to add a section with 2 radio buttons (I set one option as checked to avoid any validation on the field), now the form submits no matter if the fields have information in them or not.

**Subset of default.aspx**

```
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <label for="txtAgencyName">Name of Agency</label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgencyName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAgencyName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required" ControlToValidate="txtAgencyName" ValidationGroup="vg1" CssClass="rfvErrors"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div> 

        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <label for="txtEmail">Email Address</label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="vg1" CssClass="rfvErrors"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address" CssClass="revErrors" ValidationExpression="(^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$)" ValidationGroup="vg1" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>      
        </div>

        <!-- This is the section that is breaking the validation -->

        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <asp:RadioButton ID="rbOwnershipAgent" runat="server" Checked="true" GroupName="Ownership" />
          <asp:RadioButton ID="rbOwnershipReferral" runat="server" GroupName="Ownership" />
        </div> 

        <!-- --------------------------------------------------- -->

        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <label for="txtAgencyContact">Agency Contact Name</label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgencyContact" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAgencyContact" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required" ControlToValidate="txtAgencyContact" ValidationGroup="vg1" CssClass="rfvErrors"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div> 

        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <label for="txtPhone">Telephone Number</label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTelephone" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required" ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ValidationGroup="vg1" CssClass="rfvErrors"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div> 

        <div>
          <label for="ddlState">State</label>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select State" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
        </div> 

        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <label for="taCarriers">In your agency, who are the carriers writing liquor liability for you today?</label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="taCarriers" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvOtherCarriers" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required" ControlToValidate="taCarriers" ValidationGroup="vg1" CssClass="rfvErrors" style="margin-top:15px;"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div> 

    <div style="width:100%;margin-top:20px;border-bottom:1px solid #27a0d6"></div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit &raquo;" name="bnSubmit" class="submit" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
  </form>
```

Am I missing something simple as far as an attribute on the submit button or radio buttons? I'm just surprised that a built in .Net control is causing this kind of trouble for something this basic.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does Firebug / Developer Tools report any JavaScript error?

Comment: I copied the code you provided as is into a new page and all of the validators appear to be working for me. I get the "*Required" message if the textboxes don't have any text in them. Is there any JavaScript or anything we aren't seeing?

Comment: You code works as intended. At least all field validations works and didn't submit the form when I tried locally. There could be something else causing the issue which we don't see it in your posting. Or clean the solution and try re-building it if it helps.

Comment: I think my issue was having a couple of RequiredFieldValidator controls commented out. After you all said it worked I removed them from my code.  Should I just delete this question?